# Запрос к базе mysql, с нетривиальными условиями

Tags: php, mysql

Есть таблица users (id|name|email). Таблица огромная, более 100 миллионов записей. Поле id - автоинкремент. Поле email может быть пустым, содержать один адрес или несколько адресов, разделённые запятыми (vasya@mail.ru,petya@gmail.com,sasha@yahoo.com).

Стоит задача сделать выборку доменов адресов (часть адреса после @) с отображением количества пользователей по каждому домену, например:

mail.ru - 391183 пользователей
gmail.com - 7599309 пользователей
и т.д.

Заранее домены не известны.
Мне понятно, что надо как-то группировать по доменам, но ни какой конкретной мысли нет.

Прошу помощи знатоков. Я 8 часов голову ломал. Мозг скис ))

PS: Простой перебор в цикле - не вариант, так как это чрезмерно долгая и дорогая операция, а база боевая, под нагрузкой.

Comment: 0) Какой [censored] надизайнил *несколько адресов, разделённые запятыми*? 1) Версия MySQL? 2) Есть ли максимальное число адресов в поле одной записи?

Comment: когда БД под нагрузкой, то вытягивание на клиента одного поля может оказаться гораздо дешевле и дружелюбнее к системе ввода вывода сервера БД, чем группировка 100 млн записей по части текста, причем с потенциальным размножением записей, для доставания дополнительных email.

Comment: Возможно стОит все-таки: первым шагом нормализовать таблицу (либо создать рядом нормализованную), чтобы на каждую запись был 1 емейл, а вторым, - вынуть в отдельное поле домен емейла. Далее групировка тривиальна

Comment: Спасибо за комментарии.
К сожалению, редизайн базы не предвидится (руководство не готово).
Версия mysql 5.6
Максимального числа адресов у одной записи нет.
Очень не хочется, но, видимо, придётся таки рядом создавать нормализованную БД.
Просто я думал я чего-то не знаю, так сказать, не нашёл ещё философский камень.